# How do i fix pymongo.errors.OperationFailure:

Tags: python, pymongo

The error I get is:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: bad auth : Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth : Authentication failed.', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
```

Comment: What have you tried sofar?

Comment: check your username and password used to connect to MongoDB. This error occurs when the username or password is incorrect.

Comment: Tried.....Failed..deccided to host on the database locally